# how to change div class with angular checkbox

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cant seem to figure out how to change the class with a checkbox value. I can show/hide a class but I need a col-md-6 to change to a col-md-12. I have a map and a chart on the same row. I would like to be able to hide the map and make the chart the full width of the row. And vice versa

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdtk370z/)

```
<div ng-app>
<div >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="A" ng-false-value="B" ng-model="check"/>        
</div>

 <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:yellow">
     hide me if checkbox is true
</div>
<br/>
<div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:pink">

    change me to col-md-12 when checkbox is true
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide). Ng-hide will hide an element based on the value of check in your model. Ng-class will conditionally set a class based on a the value of check in your model.

For example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div >
        <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="A" ng-false-value="B" ng-model="check"/>        
    </div>
    
     <div class="col-md-6" ng-hide="check === 'A'" style="background-color:yellow">
         hide me if checkbox is true
    </div>
    <br/>
    
    <div ng-class="{'col-md-12': check === 'A', 'col-md-6': check === 'B'}" style="background-color:pink">
        change me to col-md-12 when checkbox is true
    </div>  
</div>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wdtk370z/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
<div ng-app>
<div >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="A" ng-false-value="B" ng-model="check"/>        
</div>
 <div class="col-md-6" ng-show="check=='B'" style="background-color:yellow">
     hide me if checkbox is true
</div>
<br/>
<div ng-class="check=='B'?'col-md-12':'col-md-6'" style="background-color:pink">

    change me to col-md-12 when checkbox is true
</div>
```

check this fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/devjit/wdtk370z/3/